# How to position right an element in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

In my page, I have an SVG. In that I would like to position the following element to right.

```
<text x="10" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
```

I know, I can give a value to position it on the x-axis, but is there a way, like in css (right: 0), to position this element always to the right edge? It is important to be an inline style, because later I want to export this SVG using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the *x* to **100%** and *text-anchor* to **end** your text will be aligned from the right edge.

```html
    <svg width="100%" height="100">
        <text x="100%" y="50" text-anchor="end" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
    </svg>
```